# Restrict duplicate form inputs across different forms

Tags: jquery, html, forms

My form inputs cannot be same in the same form and also across forms i.e., No two form names or form surnames or (form name and form surname) cannot be same. I can achieve this with my following code. I don't know how much space and time it consumes and what all bugs it can deliver.Is it recommendable to use two for loops? Is there any other better way? If so,Please Suggest...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $(".button").on("click", function () {
                    var f1name = $("#f1name").val();
                    var f1surname = $("#f1surname").val();
                    var f2name = $("#f2name").val();
                    var f2surname = $("#f2surname").val();
                    var f3name = $("#f3name").val();
                    var f3surname = $("#f3surname").val();
                    var f4name = $("#f4name").val();
                    var f4surname = $("#f4surname").val();
                    var names = [f1name, f1surname, f2name, f2surname, f3name, f3surname, f4name, f4surname];
                    //console.log(names);
                    //console.log(isDuplicateFound(names));
                    if (isDuplicateFound(names)) {
                        alert("Names and surnames cannot be same in same form and across forms");
                        return false;
                    }
                    function isDuplicateFound(names) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                            for (var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
                                if (i != j && names[i] == names[j]) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="f1" name="f1">
            <input type="text" id="f1name" name="f1name">
            <input type="text" id="f1surname" name="f1surname">
            <input type="button" class="button" value="Save">
        </form>
        <form method="post" id="f2" name="f2">
            <input type="text" id="f2name" name="f2name">
            <input type="text" id="f2surname" name="f2surname">
            <input type="button" class="button" value="Save">
        </form>
        <form method="post" id="f3" name="f3">
            <input type="text" id="f3name" name="f3name">
            <input type="text" id="f3surname" name="f3surname">
            <input type="button" class="button" value="Save">
        </form>
        <form method="post" id="f4" name="f4">
            <input type="text" id="f4name" name="f4name">
            <input type="text" id="f4surname" name="f4surname">
            <input type="button" class="button" value="Save">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also use nested loops but I suggest using class instead of ID e.g. **name** class and **username** class and using *jquery each*:

```
$(".button").on("click", function () {
   var $current;

   $(".name").each(function () {
      $current=$(this);
      $(".name").not(this).each(function(){
            if($current.val() == $(this).val()) { return false; }
      });
    });

   $(".username").each(function () {
      $current=$(this);
      $(".username").not(this).each(function(){
            if($current.val() == $(this).val()) { return false; }
      });
    });

  return true;
 });
```

Comment: Code is perfectly working alright but val() is misinterpreted as val. Thanks for the code looking simple and accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Some optimization suggestions:

**1. Declare the function `isDuplicateFound(names)` outside of the click event.**

if you declare it inside, it will be done every time you click. Put it in the `$(document).ready()`, but not in the click event block itself.

**2. `for`-optimization**

When running through the loops, you're doing a couple of useless checks. Also, you can drop your `i != j`-check with declaring `j = i + 1`, you also avoid the duplicate checks. So your final code would look like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function isDuplicateFound(names) {
                for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = i + 1; j < names.length; j++) {
                        if (names[i] == names[j]) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            $(".button").on("click", function () {
                var f1name = $("#f1name").val();
                var f1surname = $("#f1surname").val();
                var f2name = $("#f2name").val();
                var f2surname = $("#f2surname").val();
                var f3name = $("#f3name").val();
                var f3surname = $("#f3surname").val();
                var f4name = $("#f4name").val();
                var f4surname = $("#f4surname").val();
                var names = [f1name, f1surname, f2name, f2surname, f3name, f3surname, f4name, f4surname];
                //console.log(names);
                //console.log(isDuplicateFound(names));
                if (isDuplicateFound(names)) {
                    alert("Names and surnames cannot be same in same form and across forms");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
```

`for`-loops inside each other slow down the performance exponentially, but in my opinion, this is not a big deal if it's only used for checking 8 array elements.

If you don't want to use arrays, you can do it like so:

Give the inputs a common class (e.g. `name_input`). Then, you can use jQuery's `.each()` method to iterate over them.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function noDuplicates() {
        var duplicates = true;
        $('.name_input').each(function(key) {
            for (var i = key + 1; i < $('.name_input').length; i++) {
                if ($(this).val() === $('.name_input').eq(i).val()) {
                    duplicates = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        return duplicates;
    }
    $('body').on('click', '.buttn', function () {
        if (noDuplicates()) {
            console.log('No duplicates');
        }
        else {
            console.log('Duplicates found!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Keshpeth for your valuable suggestion. But is there any other way without using Arrays at all.

Comment: Somewhere "$('.name_input')[i].val()" this is throwing an error

Comment: @Aditya Rao oh right, sorry, my bad. Updated my answer with a working version. Also, i found a weird property of jQuery's `.each()` - if you return true within it, it doesn't actually return true and just keeps going until it's finished, so i had to switch out your uses of `false` and `true` for it to work efficiently (renamed the function accordingly).

Comment: don't use "return false;" instead use "break;" statement.

Comment: `break` doesn't work here, it only works on native javascript loops, so you have to use `return false;` - [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/) example 3

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I don't know that. One more thing learned today ;)

Answer (score 1):

Some optimizations:

Add classes to your form's input elements like `<input type="text" class="val-getter">`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<form method="post" id="f1" name="f1">
    <input type="text" class="val-getter" id="f1name" name="f1name">
    <input type="text" id="f1surname" class="val-getter" name="f1surname">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Save"> </form>
<form method="post" id="f2" name="f2">
    <input type="text" class="val-getter" id="f2name" name="f2name">
    <input type="text" class="val-getter" id="f2surname" name="f2surname">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Save"> </form>
<form method="post" id="f3" name="f3">
    <input type="text" id="f3name" class="val-getter" name="f3name">
    <input type="text" id="f3surname" class="val-getter" name="f3surname">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Save"> </form>
<form method="post" id="f4" name="f4">
    <input type="text" class="val-getter" id="f4name" name="f4name">
    <input type="text" class="val-getter" id="f4surname" name="f4surname">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Save"> </form>
```

This will allow you to get all the values of your name fields at once by the following JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".button").click(function(){
  var names = $(".val-getter").map(function(){
   return $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  });
  if(!names.length){
   alert("empty values!");
   return false;
  }
  if(names.length === jQuery.unique(names).length){
   alert("No Duplicates");
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 });
});
```

We get all the values of the input names from the class `.val-getter` and stored in the names variable. I have also converted the `names` to *lowercase* to ensure correct checking.

I have also added a check for empty array i.e. no values entered. *That could essentially break the logic if not present*

I have used the `jQuery.unique()` function to check for duplicates such that:
*no first name or surnames will have the same values across all forms*.
By comparing the length of the original array and the array we get after `unique()` function as it removes any duplicates in the array.